# PHP check if variable is a whole number

Tags: php, integer, double, numbers

I have this PHP code:

```
$entityElementCount = (-($highScore-$totalKeywordCount))/0.29;
```

What i want to know is, how to check whether **$entityElementCount** is a whole number (2, 6, ...) or partial (2.33, 6.2, ...).

Thank you!

Comment: Besides the other answers, for **strings**, use `ctype_digit($num)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$entityElementCount = (-($highScore-$totalKeywordCount))/0.29;
if (ctype_digit($entityElementCount) ){
    // (ctype_digit((string)$entityElementCount))  // as advised.
    print "whole number\n";
}else{
    print "not whole number\n";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have rushed with the answer. You just need to convert $entityElementCount into string before using ctype_digit function, in order for code above to work.

Comment: So, if (ctype_digit((string)$entityElementCount)) should do it.

Comment: Note: `ctype_digit('10.00')` will return FALSE, indicating "not whole number" in this example

Comment: @Philipp can you try to break my solution next?

Answer (score 62):

```
if (floor($number) == $number)
```

Comment: Try this, $number = (-(4.42-5))/0.29; After calculations $number = 2, but the condition above fails to tell that it is a whole number

Comment: Try var_dump on $number. It's a float, which is why this isn't working. Floats are imprecise.

Comment: the correct usage would be if(is_numeric($number) && floor($number) == $number) ... because floor('banana') == 'banana' is true.

Comment: I wondered why so many votes. I'd remove this answer if I posted it.

Comment: @spacemonkey WRONG, it's not a whole number. after calculations, $number is `2.000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125` (on 64bit php at least), and Tyler's code is working fine. - try `$number = (-(4.42-5))/0.29; var_dump(number_format($number,100));` to see $number with all of its digits (most functions, like echo/var_dump/etc does not show all digits, but number_format, with correct arguments, does.)

Comment: @Shafizadeh excellent point. made an [improved version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57153658/1067003) which doesn't make that mistake

Answer (score 46):

I know this is old, but I thought I'd share something I just found:

Use [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) and check for 0

```
$entityElementCount = (-($highScore-$totalKeywordCount))/0.29;
if (fmod($entityElementCount,1) !== 0.0) {
    echo 'Not a whole number!';
} else {
    echo 'A whole number!';
}
```

fmod is different from % because if you have a fraction, % doesn't seem to work for me (it returns 0...for example, `echo 9.4 % 1;` will output `0`). With fmod, you'll get the fraction portion. For example:

`echo fmod(9.4, 1);`

Will output `0.4`

Comment: @Flavius Thanks! I posted this way after an answer was accepted. I just put it here because I thought it was pretty useful. Over time, it may get more upvotes from people like you :)

Comment: This answer seems the best one.

Comment: If you want to do type matching (`===` or `!==`), as recommended by most security consultants,  fmod returns a float so you will need to do something like: `fmod($a, 1) === 0.0` to insure it is a whole number. I'm not entirely sure this is accurate either though. It's unfortunate that fmod returns a float.

Comment: @danielson317 thanks for the tip. I haven't touched PHP in years so I didn't realize that it had that type of equality operator. As for it being unfortunate that `fmod` returns a float, how come? Returning a floating point is the function's purpose (fmod = "float modulus"). Also, I tested out your theory and you're right, it would need to be ` !== 0.0`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Joseph A float is by nature an estimated number. If it returned a double the expression would be guaranteed to be accurate while a float may look like 0.0 and even print as 0.0 but not be `===0.0` due to some estimation in the processing. Realistically PHP just isn't designed for currency where this would actually make a difference. An keep in mind that the accuracy may change according to `precision` in php.ini

Comment: @danielson317 ah, ok, I see what you mean now - that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 16):

I would use [intval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function like this:

```
if($number === intval($number)) {

}
```

Tests:

```
var_dump(10 === intval(10));     // prints "bool(true)"
var_dump("10" === intval("10")); // prints "bool(false)"
var_dump(10.5 === intval(10.5)); // prints "bool(false)"
var_dump("0x539" === intval("0x539")); // prints "bool(false)"
```

### Other solutions

**1)**

```
if(floor($number) == $number) {   // Currently most upvoted solution:
```

Tests:

```
$number = true;
var_dump(floor($number) == $number); // prints "bool(true)" which is incorrect.
```

**2)**

```
if (is_numeric($number) && floor($number) == $number) {
```

Corner case:

```
$number = "0x539";
var_dump(is_numeric($number) && floor($number) == $number); // prints "bool(true)" which depend on context may or may not be what you want
```

**3)**

```
if (ctype_digit($number)) {
```

Tests:

```
var_dump(ctype_digit("0x539")); // prints "bool(false)"
var_dump(ctype_digit(10)); // prints "bool(false)"
var_dump(ctype_digit(0x53)); // prints "bool(false)"
```

Answer (score 13):

The basic way, as Chacha said is

```
if (floor($number) == $number)
```

However, floating point types cannot accurately store numbers, which means that 1 might be stored as 0.999999997. This will of course mean the above check will fail, because it will be rounded down to 0, even though for your purposes it is **close enough** to 1 to be considered a whole number. Therefore try something like this:

```
if (abs($number - round($number)) < 0.0001)
```

Comment: I'd say this is the best solution, given the nature of floats.  Just pick a precision level that suits your task.

Comment: fails on "123foobar" (it thinks 123foobar is a whole number) - i really like the precision adjustment though

Answer (score 7):

I tested all the proposed solutions with many problematic values mentioned, they all fail for at least one of the test cases. Start checking if `$value` is a number using `is_numeric($value)` reduces the number of failures for many solutions, but does not turn any solution into an ultimate one:

```
$test_cases = array(0.29, 2, 6, 2.33, 6.2, '10.00', 1.4, 10, "10", 10.5, "0x539", true,
    false, 0x53, 9.4, "ten", "100", 1, 0.999999997, 0, 0.0001, 1.0, 0.9999999,
    (-(4.42-5))/0.29);

function is_whole_number($value) {
    // Doing this prevents failing for values like true or "ten"
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    // @ghostdog74's solution fails for "10.00"
    // return (ctype_digit((string) $value));

    // Both @Maurice's solutions fails for "10.00"
    // return ((string) $value === (string) (int) $value);
    // return is_int($value);

    // @j.hull's solution always returns true for numeric values
    // return (abs($value) % 1 == 0 ? true : false);

    // @ MartyIX's solution fails for "10.00"
    // return ($value === intval($value));

    // This one fails for (-(4.42-5))/0.29
    // return (floor($value) == $value);

    // This one fails for 2
    // return ctype_digit($value);

    // I didn't understand Josh Crozier's answer

    // @joseph4tw's solution fails for (-(4.42-5))/0.29
    // return !(fmod($value, 1) != 0);

    // If you are unsure about the double negation, doing this way produces the same
    // results:
    // return (fmod($value, 1) == 0);

    // Doing this way, it always returns false 
    // return (fmod($value, 1) === 0);

    // @Anthony's solution fails for "10.00"
    // return (is_numeric($value) && is_int($value));

    // @Aistina's solution fails for 0.999999997
    // return (abs($value - round($value)) < 0.0001);

    // @Notinlist's solution fails for 0.999999997
    // return (round($value, 3) == round($value));
}

foreach ($test_cases as $test_case) {
    var_dump($test_case);
    echo ' is a whole number? ';
    echo is_whole_number($test_case) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    echo "\n";
}
```

I think that solutions like the ones proposed by @Aistina and @Notinlist are the best ones, because they use an error threshold to decide whether a value is a whole number. It is important to note that they worked as expected for the expression `(-(4.42-5))/0.29`, while all the others failed in that test case.

I decided to use @Notinlist's solution because of its readability:

```
function is_whole_number($value) {
    return (is_numeric($value) && (round($value, 3) == round($value)));
}
```

I need to test if values are whole numbers, currency or percentage, I think 2 digits of precision is enough, so @Notinlist's solution fits my needs.

Running this test:

```
$test_cases = array(0.29, 2, 6, 2.33, 6.2, '10.00', 1.4, 10, "10", 10.5, "0x539", true,
    false, 0x53, 9.4, "ten", "100", 1, 0.999999997, 0, 0.0001, 1.0, 0.9999999,
    (-(4.42-5))/0.29);

function is_whole_number($value) {
    return (is_numeric($value) && (round($value, 3) == round($value)));
}

foreach ($test_cases as $test_case) {
    var_dump($test_case);
    echo ' is a whole number? ';
    echo is_whole_number($test_case) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    echo "\n";
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
float(0.29)
 is a whole number? no
int(2)
 is a whole number? yes
int(6)
 is a whole number? yes
float(2.33)
 is a whole number? no
float(6.2)
 is a whole number? no
string(5) "10.00"
 is a whole number? yes
float(1.4)
 is a whole number? no
int(10)
 is a whole number? yes
string(2) "10"
 is a whole number? yes
float(10.5)
 is a whole number? no
string(5) "0x539"
 is a whole number? yes
bool(true)
 is a whole number? no
bool(false)
 is a whole number? no
int(83)
 is a whole number? yes
float(9.4)
 is a whole number? no
string(3) "ten"
 is a whole number? no
string(3) "100"
 is a whole number? yes
int(1)
 is a whole number? yes
float(0.999999997)
 is a whole number? yes
int(0)
 is a whole number? yes
float(0.0001)
 is a whole number? yes
float(1)
 is a whole number? yes
float(0.9999999)
 is a whole number? yes
float(2)
 is a whole number? yes
```

Comment: The main problem with your algorithm is `0.999999997` is not a whole number.

Comment: As I said, I needed to test if values were whole numbers, currency or percentage, so I adopted 2 digits of precision. In case you need to adjust the precision, just change `round($value, 3)`. Using `round($value, 9)` produces `float(0.999999997) is a whole number? no`.

Comment: So keep in mind all of this is also subject to the `precision` setting in `php.ini`. If you have that set to 8 or less then `float(0.999999997)` is a whole number. But if you set it to say 20 , then `float(0.999999997) => 0.99999999699999997382`. The default is 14 I think so would still create a discrepancy. Your algorithm will work great for statistics, which is it's purpose here, but not currency nor input validation.

Answer (score 6):

If you know that it will be numeric (meaning it won't ever be a an integer cast as a string, like `"ten"` or `"100"`, you can just use `is_int()`:

```
$entityElementCount = (-($highScore-$totalKeywordCount))/0.29;
$entityWholeNumber = is_int($entityElementCount);

echo ($entityWholeNumber) ? "Whole Number!" : "Not a whole number!";
```

Comment: Good, but the ternary operator here is redundant. Just
`$entityWholeNumber = is_int($entityElementCount)` is sufficient

Comment: Your two code samples do exactly the same, the second just stores the result from the `is_int` call in a var (in a rather cumbersome way, I might add). Also, this checks if the var is an int, not if the value contained is a whole number.

Comment: Integers are always whole numbers. If what he wants is to know if it's a whole number or a non-whole number, that means it's either an integer or a float. The code samples are supposed to do the same thing.

Comment: by definition, integers are like whole number, but they can include negative sign. Whole numbers don't have negative sign.

Comment: @ghostdog74 - Whole numbers can be negative. You're thinking of natural numbers, which also can't include 0. And the user didn't ask if it would be whole and real, just whole. Integers and whole numbers are the same thing. Not to mention that any of the rounding techniques offered would also not check if the number is less than 0.

Comment: And please don't say "by definition" unless you can cite your dictionary. By definition integers are all whole numbers, including all natural numbers and their negative counterpart. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Answer (score 3):

```
if(floor($number) == $number)
```

Is not a stable algorithm. When a value is matematically 1.0 the numerical value can be 0.9999999. If you apply floor() on it it will be 0 which is not equals to 0.9999999.

You have to guess a precision radius for example 3 digits

```
if(round($number,3) == round($number))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    $num = 2.0000000000001;
    if( $num == floor( $num  ) ){
        echo('whole');
    }else{
        echo('fraction');
    }
```

EX:

2.0000000000001   | fraction

2.1               | fraction

2.00              | whole

2                 | whole

Answer (score 3):

Another hacky way I came up with is `ceil($value) === floor($value)`. If a number is a whole number, this should always be true, even if comparing 10 with 10.000 and will even work with numbers cast in string, for example `ceil("10.0") === floor(10)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(string)floor($pecahformat[3])!=(string)$pecahformat[3]
```

Comment: fails on both `$pecahformat=123.5`  and fails on `$pecahformat="123.5"`, it thinks 123.5 is a whole number.

Answer (score 2):

improved version of @Tyler Carter's solution, which handles edge cases better than the original:

```
function is_whole_number($number){
    return (is_float(($f=filter_var($number,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT))) && floor($f)===$f);    
}
```

(Tyler's code fail to recognize that the string "123foobar" is not a whole number. this improved version won't make that mistake. credits to @Shafizadeh in the comments for discovering the bug. also this is php7 `strict_types=1`-compatible)

Answer (score 1):

```
floor($entityElementCount) == $entityElementCount
```

This will be true if this is a whole number

Comment: Not for all floats. php -r "$n = (-(4.42-5))/0.29;var_dump($n, floor($n) == $n);"
float(2)
bool(false)

Comment: fails on `$entityElementCount="123foobar";`  (it thinks 123foobar is a whole number.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an attempt to answer this question so much. Their are plenty of answer already. If you are doing statistics as the question implies I suspect @antonio-vinicius-menezes-medei answer will suite you best. However I needed this answer for input validation. I found this check more reliable for validating an input string is a whole number:

`is_numeric($number) && preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $number)`

The 'is_numeric' simply corrects for "true" converting to "1" in preg_match.

So playing off of @antonio-vinicius-menezes-medei answer. I wrote a script to test this below. Note the `ini_set('precision', 20)`. preg_match will convert the argument to a string. If your precicion is set below the length of the float values they will simply round at the given precision. Similar to @antonio-vinicius-menezes-medei answer this precision setting will force a similar estimation length.

```
  ini_set('precision', 20);
  $test_cases = array(0.29, 2, 6, 2.33, 6.2, '10.00', 1.4, 10, "10", 10.5, "0x539", true,
    false, 0x53, 9.4, "ten", "100", 1, 0.999999997, 0, 0.0001, 1.0, 0.9999999,
    (-(4.42-5))/0.29);

  foreach ($test_cases as $number)
  {
    echo '<strong>';
    var_dump($number);
    echo '</strong>';
    echo boolFormater(is_numeric($number) && preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $number));
    echo '<br>';
  }

  function boolFormater($value)
  {
    if ($value)
    {
      return 'Yes';
    }
    return 'No';
  }
```

Which produces this output:

**float(0.28999999999999998002)** No
**int(2)** Yes
**int(6)** Yes
**float(2.3300000000000000711)** No
**float(6.2000000000000001776)** No
**string(5) "10.00"** No
**float(1.3999999999999999112)** No
**int(10)** Yes
**string(2) "10"** Yes
**float(10.5)** No
**string(5) "0x539"** No
**bool(true)** No
**bool(false)** No
**int(83)** Yes
**float(9.4000000000000003553)** No
**string(3) "ten"** No
**string(3) "100"** Yes
**int(1)** Yes
**float(0.99999999699999997382)** No
**int(0)** Yes
**float(0.00010000000000000000479)** No
**float(1)** Yes
**float(0.99999990000000005264)** No
**float(2.0000000000000004441)** No

Answer (score 1):

Just to share my solution with localized string/number, this combo worked like a charm for me.

```
public static function isWholeNumber ($input, $decimalDelimiter = ',')
{
    if (is_string($input)){
        $input = str_replace($decimalDelimiter, '.', $input);
        $input = floatval($input);
    }

    if (fmod($input,1) !== 0.0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ($your_number % ceil($your_number) == 0) {

  //Number is whole

} else {

  //Number is not whole

}
```

Comment: It is a great solution and works with numbers as a string type as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What seems a simple approach would be to use modulus (%) to determine if a value is whole or not.

```
x = y % 1
```

if y is anything other then a whole number the result is not a zero (0).  A test then would be:

```
if (y % 1 == 0) { 
   // this is a whole number  
} else { 
   // this is not a whole number 
}

var isWhole = (y % 1 == 0? true: false);  // to get a boolean return.
```

Granted this will view a negative number as a whole number, then then just wrap ABS() around `y` to always test on the positive.

Comment: This is actually not true. For some reason 1.4 % 1 returns 0. I assume  php casts to int before doing the modulus.

fmod(1.4, 1) however does return the expected 0.4

Comment: you could do `(x * 5.0) % 5.0)` but only if the decimals in x are at least .1 because of the rounding that php does.

Answer (score 0):

I always use typecasting to check if variables contain a whole number, handy when you don't know the origin or type of the value.

```
if ((string) $var === (string) (int) $var) {
    echo 'whole number';
} else {
    echo 'whatever it is, it\'s something else';
}
```

In your particular case, I would use [is_int()](http://php.net/is_int)

```
if (is_int($var) {
    echo 'integer';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for positive whole numbers only. This may not work for everything.

```
$string = '0x539';
$ceil = ceil($string);

if($ceil < 1){
  $ceil = FALSE; // or whatever you want i.e 0 or 1
}

echo $ceil; // 1337
```

You can use floor() instead of ceil() if so desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isInteger($value)
{
    // '1' + 0 == int, '1.2' + 0 == float, '1e2' == float
    return is_numeric($value) && is_int($value + 0);
}

function isWholeNumber($value)
{
    return is_numeric($value)
        && (is_int($value + 0)
            || (intval($value + 0) === intval(ceil($value + 0))));
}
```

If you want to check for both whole and decimal numbers, you can do the following:

```
if (isInteger($foo))
{
    // integer as int or string
}
if (isWholeNumber($foo))
{
    // integer as int or string, or float/double with zero decimal part
}
else if (is_numeric($foo))
{
    // decimal number - still numeric, but not int
}
```

This will correctly check your number without rounding it, casting it to int (which in the case of a decimal number will lose the decimal part), or doing any math. If, however, you want to treat `1.00` as a whole number, then that's a whole another story.

Comment: Sorry in my PHP, interpreter, php -r "var_dump(is_int(log(8, 2) + 0));" =>
bool(false)

Comment: It is false for me too, because log(8, 2) = float/double, not int. I don't think you understand what this does. The +0 is only needed to convert numeric strings to numbers.

Comment: The original question was regarding floats. @jurchiks Sorry I was just pointing out that this answer doesn't work.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me... Do you not see the `is_int()` in my function? Floats are not whole numbers.

Comment: No sorry. No jokes intended. You end up with numbers represented as floats that are in fact whole numbers as in the OP's code.

Comment: That's not a problem with my code. If my function receives a float, it will obviously say it's not an int. Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: My reason for showing up to this page was determining if floats were whole as was the OP's question. Just seemed out of place or wrong as an answer is all.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old post but this is a simple function that will return a valid whole number and cast it to an int. Returns false if it fails.

```
function isWholeNumber($v)
{
    if ($v !='' && is_numeric($v) && strpos($v, '.') === false) {
        return (int)$v;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage :

```
$a = 43;
$b = 4.3;
$c = 'four_three';

isWholeNumber($a) // 43
isWholeNumber($b) // false
isWholeNumber($c) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$entityElementCount = (-($highScore-$totalKeywordCount))/0.29;

Method 1-
    By using ctype_digit() function. 

    if ( ctype_digit($entityElementCount )) { 
        echo "Whole Number\n"; 
    } else { 
        echo "Not a whole Number\n"; 
    } 


Method 2-
    By using is_float() function. 

    if (is_float($entityElementCount )) { 
        echo "Not a Whole Number\n"; 
    } else { 
        echo "Whole Number\n"; 
    } 


Method 3-
    By using is_int() function. 

    if (is_int($entityElementCount )) { 
        echo "Whole Number\n"; 
    } else { 
        echo "Not a whole Number\n"; 
    } 


Method 5-
    By using fmod() function. 

    It needs 2 parameters one dividend and other is divisor
    Here $dividend=$entityElementCount and divisor=1
    if (fmod($dividend,$divisor) !== 0.0) {
        echo 'Not a whole number!';
    } else {
     echo 'A whole number!';
    }

there are some more function like intval(), floor(),... can be used to check it`enter code here`
```