# How do i check that in 100.00 number after decimal point is greater than 0 or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Actually I want to know that if number is 0.75 then consider it as value and if number is 75.00 then consider it as percentage and if number is 12.25 then also consider it as value

Comment: _"in 100.00 number after decimal point"_?? In general its helpful to provide sample data and an expected output. You should also always show what you've tried since that clarifies things and shows your own effort.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188675/php-check-if-variable-is-a-whole-number

Answer (score 2):

Modulus when divided by one will divide out the entire whole section and leave only the decimal remainder. try following:

```
   SELECT CASE (100.00 % 1) WHEN 0 THEN 'Percent' ELSE 'Value' END
   SELECT CASE (0.75 % 1) WHEN 0 THEN 'Percent' ELSE 'Value' END
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert to an integer and see if the original value matches.  Your question is unclear on what you want the output to be, but perhaps:

```
select (case when value between 0 and 1 then 'value'
             when cast(value as int) = value then 'percentage'
             else 'value'
        end)
```

Note:  this is potentially not perfect because of inaccuracies in using floating point representations.  It should work for decimal representations.  Note also that 12.00001 is treated as a value rather than a percentage.  Your question is quite unclear on what to do in this case.  Most floating point representations store low-valued integers exactly, so this will work for exact matches.

If you only care about the first two decimal places, you can use the `str()` function or a double cast.  For instance, for positive values:

```
select (case when value between 0 and 1 then 'value'
             when right(str(value - floor(value as int), 10, 2), 2) = '00' then 'percentage'
             else 'value'
        end)
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful to me. Thank You Gordon Linoff