# Show only one decimal place or nothing of a floating point number

Tags: php

I'm aware of `number_format(..)` that behaves like following:

```
number_format(2.5, 1) // returns 2.5
number_format(2.0, 1) // returns 2.0 <-- needs to be just 2
```

The problem is, that I don't want `.0` to be shown at all. How to format the float correctly to achieve this?

Comment: Check if is a whole number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188675/php-check-if-variable-is-a-whole-number and than apply `number_format()`.

Comment: @jszobody yes, your answer was the best one, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `round` instead of `number_format`:

```
echo round(2.0, 1); // 2
echo round(2.5, 1); // 2.5
echo round(2.555555, 1); // 2.6
echo round(2.501, 1); // 2.5
echo round(2.1050, 1); // 2.1
```

Another option is to cast your number to a float after using `number_format`, which will eliminate any trailing zeros after the decimal point.

```
echo (float) number_format(2.0, 1); // 2
echo (float) number_format(2.5, 1); // 2.5
echo (float) number_format(2.555555, 1); // 2.6
echo (float) number_format(2.501, 1); // 2.5
echo (float) number_format(2.1050, 1); // 2.1
```

Both will give you a *maximum* of a single decimal place. I think `round` is the better option here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)? Like this `number_format(2.0, is_float(2.0) ? 1 : 0)`